# I want to set value in XML through Robot Framework 4.0 XML library

Tags: python, robotframework

Please find the below XML body. I need to set the value of the Key.

```
<Order ID="Machine" Accepting="Y"ReleaseDate="Y" Key="1234567890123456" Release="N"/>
```

I have tried:

```
Set Element Attribute  ${XML}  Key  ${order_header_key}
```